# Sending encrypted text, and decrypting on the server later - what's a solid built-in PHP function?

Tags: php, security, encryption

Alright, I've been through many ideas (a lot on SO as well)... but I think I found the money maker.

1. I have some sensitive information that users enter on a form.
2. Upon Submission of this form, the information will be *encrypted* with a key (unique to that user, only known by that user), and this encrypted text will be sent over email to the user's email.  The (unencrypted) text is <20 characters, usually.
3. The user will then be able to log into the website, using a password unique to them.  They can then enter the encrypted string, along with their unique key, and will view the unencrypted information (I can decrypt it with the key they provide - the key is stored in the DB just like a password would be - it's hashed, and the hash is compared upon user entry).

In this fashion, nothing sensitive is stored on the server.  In fact, nothing encrypted is stored on the server either (except the KEY's hash).  The user has complete control of the data.

If this work flow sounds ok - what are some PHP functions and options that people would suggest for strong encryption?  Any samples floating around there for something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to reinvent the wheel. Just use symmetric cypher over https and you are done.

Comment: It may depend on the nature of the content. What kind of information will be stored in emails and how long, etc. Basically you're proposing using email as a storage which is kind of out of the box. Could be positive or negative. It's definitely not usual. More information please!

Comment: @markus This will be small information.  Less than VARCHAR 255, ha!  Most often , <20 characters.  I will also add:  The users will be instructed to delete these emails after they are received.  Finally, there are MANY different users, so the point isn't to store the info - but instead to leave it in their hands, rather than on our servers.

Comment: Again, what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @markus check my latest comment in CSJOHN's answer below.

Comment: But what information is it, why does it need to be done like that, is it so different from any other application in the net, why don't others do it like this? Point is, it most probably is the wrong approach but it is hard to say because you're not telling us what it is all about.

Comment: @markus it's proprietary information that the customer treats like a social...

Comment: You might not be storing it *permanently* on the server - but it is stored temporarily and *un*encrypted versions are flying back and forth - I wouldn't be using this. Why not encrypt/decrypt on the browser and store/transfer the encrypted data?

Comment: @symcbean Where do you see unencrypted versions flying back and forth in this scenario?  Maybe I'm missing something....

Comment: @Shackrock: "log into the website...enter the encrypted string...view the unencrypted information" implies that the website decrypts the data and sends iot back to the browser

Comment: @symcbean: Yes sir, that's exactly what will happen.  Run it through a function and display it to the browser (over SSL).

Answer (score 1):

What happens if the user loses the key?

UPDATE:
If you really want it to be secure, the user could encrypt the data on their side before it's sent to the application (with constraints on the level of PKI bit level and algorithm). Then, it doesn't matter what you do with it, because it'll be encrypted. However, you won't be able to decrypt it.

If that option doesn't work for you because you need to read it, create a second system that is only connected to the web servers (and not the internet). This system requires heavy authentication from each web server and treats each web servers as an untrusted source. So, you'd enforce security by policy. A web server wouldn't be allowed to retrieve more than X number of user records per minute (thus, protecting the entire database from being compromised). Furthermore, you can provide heavy monitoring and reporting and you'll need to rotate the auth keys for the web server frequently.

Without knowing what the actual domain problem is, it's hard for us to recommend whether either of these methods is warranted. I'm just trying to provide you with options, should you feel they're warranted.

However, the most common security hole is people. Who has access to the server? What level of coding is on the application server? Are regular security audits performed on your system by a credible, security consulting company that has experience auditing source code in your language or framework?

Hope that helps

UPDATE:

In regards to hashing:

See: 
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/rainbow-hash-cracking.html

http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html

http://www.md5decrypter.co.uk/sha1-decrypt.aspx

Hashing must be done with care

Comment: We will have an offline storage of user keys in an encrypted container (i.e. KeePass, Truecrypt container, etc...).

Comment: If it's offline, how often does it sync?

Comment: Hmmmm, good point - you're saying how can I encrypt with a key, if the key isn't stored in the DB somehow... right?  I overlooked that.  How do you think I can store the key properly then?

Comment: Can't I store the key just as I would a password in the DB - and compare hashes?  Then, I can continue to store the real key offline in case it is lost by the user.

Comment: If you're storing the key in the database, then how does that improve security and why does it necessitate the storage offline? What's the difference between the key stored in the database and the "real key"?

Comment: The stored DB key isn't the plaintext key.  It's a hash.

Comment: If it's a hash, how will you decrypt the data for your uses?

Comment: I'll check the user entered key against the hash, if it matches, I'll use the user entered key to decrypt.

Comment: See my update regarding hashing. I think the main thing is that you think about your code and ask questions (which you're doing). Keep learning and researching and try not to become complacent. Keep up the good work. Cheers

Comment: thanks for the updated post.  Raises a question for me on your first line.  How can I have the user encrypt before it's sent to the application (they don't have the tools that my server has...)?

Comment: re: hashing.  Thanks for the links.  I'm actually pretty well versed on hashing thanks to SO about a year ago.  Using a strong, slow hashing algo - w/ salts.

Comment: Regarding your question about how they'd do it? You can use Javascript. See http://shop-js.sourceforge.net/crypto2.htm or http://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/

Comment: Wow, that's pretty awesome.  I'm worried about user error (I can't prevent somebody bypassing this JS, and just entering the unsecure information).  What is wrong with accepting the unsecure info in a form and encrypting it right away (first thing after POST)?  As long as this is done on a secure server, with SSL to the client, it sounds to me like I'm protected...

Comment: Yup. Just try to make it hard to screw up and easy to do it right and you'll be fine. But at the end of the day, it's their responsibility to make sure their computer is uncompromised, virus-free, keylogger-free, etc. You can make refuse access on HTTP on obvious login form submission pages (where the login form submits to). You can also ensure that the login form auto-redirects to HTTPS.

Comment: I just realized, as I am startnig to code this, that I def. overlooked that I need to store the key in plaintext if I expect to ENCRYPT on that key (I can't use the hash to ecnrypt the key, obviously)...  so my original idea is slightly flawed....

Answer (score 0):

Generally in security theres the principle that you're security "system" is only as strong as its weakest point. In this case I would say there are some points that are not necessarily as strong as you seem to desire.

First of all, (assuming this is a web application) there is the issue of transferring the plain-text data between the users initial point of entry and the server. You would essentially be doing this in the clear. This applies to both the info and the key! At this point I'd recommend you looking into HTTPS.

Also at this point its worth asking - if they have the key, and they have the ciphertext, why do they need you to decrypt it? Generally encryption is not something you want to do on your own (i.e. use established encryption algorithms/schemes). Since they are established/open the users would be able to decrypt without you. If its simply a matter of convenience than that might already be lost when you require that users remember a key for each piece of data, and must store and manage the cipher-text themselves.

---

Why don't you offer the service of storing the cipher-text, and use public-key cryptography. You would be able to encrypt the user data with the public key and store both on server without issue, and the users can keep the private key.

Comment: HTTPS is forced through HTACCESS, sorry I didn't mention.  I think it's more convinience for the user, than anything else.  They don't know how to run the PHP command to decrypt the text/etc... They simply use web forms =).   After thinking more on this based on you and Homer's comments...  I suppose I need to store the key on my server somehow.  Then, once they login, that key is associated with that user for decrypting (so the user only needs to memorize their password, and have their KEY somewhere as well)...  What do you think?

Comment: Is the intent of this application the ability to encrypt text and get the ciphertext, and come back and decrypt it later?

Comment: Yes sir.  To be clear:  A public user fills out a form over HTTPS.  All but 1-2 fields are NOT sensitive information.  An email is sent to the owner of the form (the user with a login), with most of the data in plaintext in the email.  However, the sensitive info will be the encrypted string.  The private user will need to login, copy/paste the encrypted string, enter their key, then they have view the result...